# Are there any good Star Wars resources about mouse droids that reference a video sensor?

Tags: star-wars, droids

I am writing a story from the perspective of a Star Wars mouse droid (seen on Death Star). Are there any good resources (short stories, cross-sections, interviews, concept sketches, etc.) which reveal the mouse droid's internals?

Specifically, I am wondering if mouse droids have a video sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

## References

- *Star Wars - The Essential Guide to Droids* (published in 1999) has mouse droid details including diagrams in pages 124/125. (I didn't check "The new Essential Guide" from 2003 but presumably it has that too).
- *Cynabar's Fantastic Technology: Droids* RPG sourcebook has some details
- For less rigorous but more volumnous secondary source, Wookieepedia:

  [MSE-6](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MSE-6-series_repair_droid) ; [MSE series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MSE-series) ; [MSF Series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MSF_mouse_droid)

## Sensors

The droid had electro-photoreceptors and auditory sensor and miniature holocam.

[image]

Comment: Curses. You beat me to it. Admittedly. I got sidetracked for 20+ minutes reading my new "Star Wars - Complete Locations" book.

Comment: @Richard - wait for 2 more days and I'm gone :)

Comment: Is there a specific date/time that you're waiting for? Just wondering...

Comment: @Richard - yes, the end of long weekend :) I keep trying to clean up my mega answers but keep getting either discouraged or distracted :)

Comment: I recall to have controlled a mouse droid in Jedi Knight: Jedi Outcast, if briefly. That too would suggest the unit possesses optical and auditory sensors.